# How to Get system hardware information in VB.NET 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to get system hardware related information such as graphics card, cpu, no. of cpu cores, etc.
I was not able to find all the info in the registry. Also where in the registry can i find info related to various drivers.

Comment: This question should be tagget winapi, not .net. It is about windows registry or something, absolutely not .net related.

Comment: Use the System.Management namespace.  Experiment with WMI queries using this tool: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572

Comment: I think it has a correct tag: a .net programmer for a .net solution may ask .net-followers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

look at this project, very nice, easy, just need to know a bit of c#

[How to get Hardware information](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx)

Comment: Sorry man, I forgot to add a reference. This answer works. Edit answer and I will remove my minus